# How to find which field is responsible for Non-Serialzable exception

Tags: java, serialization

Is there a way to list all the fields inside `myObject` which are responsible for the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-serializable object` Exception,

I know that this is thrown at `objectOutputStream.writeObject(myObject);`

As far as I know, all the objects references inside `myObject` are implementing `Serializable` Interface.

NB: `myObject` has a deep reference hierarchy which would make it extremely tedious to go through it and find the culprit manually.

Edit: I wanna do this programmatically.

Comment: How about `myObject` itself?

Comment: I think you can see it in exception stacktrace.

Comment: show us exception stacktrace

Comment: @whoAml `myObject` is implementing `Serializable`, if that's what you meant

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` throws `NotSerializableException` in this case, with the classname concerned showing in the message.I suspect your exception is coming from a class's `writeObject()` method. You will have to post the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check programmatically which instance field does not implement serializable Use reflection. Get all the fields of that class. Now iterate thru it and check if it is instance of Serializable.

Try below though.Please ignore compilation errors as i have not runt it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Object o = new X();

  for (Field field : o.getClass().getFields()) {
     if (!Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
        System.out.println("Field " + field + " is not assignable from type " + o.getClass());
     }
  }
```

}

Please note that you can mark the variable as transient also if you dont want to serialize it. So every instance variable need not to be type of serializable provided you dont want to serialize it.

Comment: This is the kind of approach I am looking for , but the `Serializable.TYPE` part doesn't seem to work.

Comment: it should be Serializable.class. Updated my post.

Comment: This is quite wrong. Back to front. It should be `Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())`. You don't need `myType` at all.

Comment: There is a bracket missing in  the if clause, needs to be (!Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()))

Answer (score 0):

the exception itself tells you what class is not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you ,in catch block

```
catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
{ 
Log.e("IllegalArgumentException",e.getMessage().toString());
 }
```

They will distinguish between same exception at other line

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` doesn't have a `getPosition()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception message doesn't tell you, you could search for it by temporarily making fields `transient` until you don't get the message anymore.

The `transient` keyword tells the serialization libraries to not serialize fields marked with it.

You could binary-search this, testing each half all at once, and then the sub-halves, until you have found it.